# MPLAB xc8 pic16f688 pragma for WDTE Ignored

Tags: pic, xc8

when using #pragma `CONFIG = WDTE OFF`
I get a message that:

> WDTE is set to ON  do I want it changed?

I do answer yes.
What concerns me is are other config statements ignored?
I can't tell.  New to PIC.
Trying to make LED flash with PIC16F688.

I got it to work, kind of.  I made sure the #pragma statements preceeded the #include and #define.  What follows is the block of `#pragma` statements that did NOT work.

```
#pragma config WDTE = 0x0
#pragma config PWRTE = 0x0
#pragma config MCLRE  = 0x0
#pragma config CP = 0x0
#pragma config CPD = 0x0
#pragma config BOREN = 0x1
#pragma config IESO = 0x1
#pragma config FCMEN =0x1
```

I went to the hex approach to avoid definitions of ON and OFF
I used MPBLAB's "set configration bits" under the RUN drop down to set the bits, changing them to hex.  This still gave the `WDTE`, then the error vanished and I picked up a PWRTE CP error. I discovered I had set MCLRE to 1, so setting it to 0 it I still received the config error messages, but the program ran.
Then, I used only the statement `#pragma config CONFIG 0xFF5`.  I got no config errors, but a warning that the 0xFF5 was going to automatically truncated to `0xFFF`.
Now it all runs, but, I cannot get debug to run.

In now with that issue, which, I suppose is a different thread.
However the questions arises as to how the configuration word is formed, what bits contribute part of the word. I tried to guess from some registers but got nowhere.  It would be nice to know.
Also, noting 0xFFF sets each bit in the word to 1 would imply that all my `#pragma config statements (bits) = 1`, which makes no sense.

I made my program and circuit run by using other troubleshooting methods.  I would like to use debug in the future.  I have read and re-read in PICkit 3 guide about `PGD` and `PGC` and having a clock running on the chip.  My o'scope says I have a running clock (internal 4 MHZ). The PIC16F688 does not use the terminology `PGD` and `PGC`, but the pins are labeled `ICSPDAT` and `ICSPCLK`, respectively.  Why debug does not work?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem? There's no clear question here. If you have some code that's not working, please post it.

Comment: @Greggoshen, you can simply edit your question above to add the most important part of the code which reproduces the behavior. The shorter this is more effective it will be. If you get that behavior there are only really 2 possible reasons. A - the bit is not called WDTE on the device and B you have redefined the meaning of OFF by having a #define before the #pragma statement. My money is on the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people define OFF in a header file and break the pragma.

Actually every single time someone has asked me this question that was the case so I am 99% sure that this is your problem.

Never include any headers before the pragma !!!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
pragma config  WDTE = OFF
pragma config  PWRTE = OFF

....
```